# android:Customize camera for QR code scanning using ZXING

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I am scanning QR code using ZXING lib and it is working fine. Now i want to customize my camera to show up only on the half of the screen and on the remaining half i want to show my linear layout. Is it possible using ZXING ? if not , is there any other lib that will allow me to do this

Comment: @ropic no i didn't tried the solution that Skunk said, coz my requirement changed. But if you have the sol pls do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, although you have to write a little more code than if you were just using an intent to the ZXing app or using their built-in activity. You need to write your own activity and layout and setup the camera preview for those objects. It isn't terribly simple if you don't know too much about ZXing or the camera, but all the information is out there. You are going to want a thread that pulls preview frames and runs them through a DataMatrixReader and handles the output.